# CSS in list with up-down

Tags: html, css

I want to make a list with CSS. Something like in the figure:

[image]

How should I proceed …

Comment: You can start by making it. What's your question?

Comment: :) :) nice very nice help

Comment: Can you be more specific? Include some code to show what you've tried.

Comment: i want to know how to create the up-down effect using css as it is there in the left part of imge

Comment: what do you mean by _'up-down effect'_ ??

Comment: up-down effect you meaned collapsible?

Comment: OP means the inset shadow. @user1853803 Please at least attempt to solve your own problems in future. A quick search for 'css inside shadow' immediate sends you [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/). I'm sure you could have found it without much exertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic that effect with `box-shadow` and a slightly darker background color:

```
div {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cWX94/**

**One more http://jsfiddle.net/cWX94/1/**

Comment: thanks blender....this is wat i was looking...accept and +1